# Library that supports Connecting to Twitter API using SSL

Tags: .net, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp, tweetinvi

I have been using both the [tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) and [teeetinvi](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/) libraries to access Twitter. Unfortunately tweetsharp is no longer supported and the release version of tweetinvi does not (yet) fully support SSL/TDS. Twitter will require SSL/TDS ([Restricting api.twitter.com to SSL/TLS traffic](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/24239)) effective January 14, 2014 with blackout testing on January 7, 2014.

Does anyone know of a library compatible with .Net (ideally C#) that fully supports SSL/TDS as well as the longer 64 bit user IDs in its released version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try linqtotwitter and see if that works for you
https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

Comment: linqtotwitter works fine - F# example here: https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/484012